# Filters by category

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a column named "category" and type of that is by choice. 
The thing is: Can i create a view by category that shows me for example choice n.2, choice n.3, etc?

Thank you

---

Thank you all for the help. 
I was not to explicit in first post
I already do all options posted here, but i select category - country type it will go to view country type.

Category it´s a drop down list. witch as: country type, department, and all of this ones are views also.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you create a view, add a filter where you define that `[Category]` `is equal to` `<Your value>`. You need to know the values beforehand, so defining the filter value as e.g. `[Category #2]` isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple view for your list for any column and datatype.
So in your case you can navigate to list settings -> all the way down and you can see option called create view and select standard view, then give appropriate name for the view and in Filter section you can select "Show items only when the following is true" and in drop down select your column name (Category) and select condition(is equal to) then give Value (n.2) and click ok

[image]

and in your list you can see newly created view name like highlighted below image, you values get change if you select respective view

[image]

Comment: This view is only for specific choice/category.
They cannot view choice n.2, choice n.3 etc. through this view.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a view from "Standard View" type.
- Under "Group by" section of view, under "First group by the column" dropdown, select the "category" column.

[image: View for category]